# sharepoint fba

Tags: sharepoint

i have a wss 3.0 site up and running using forms based authentication. Is there a way to upload multiple files (basically copy and paste a folder containing files)?

also, when i try to access the site using designer 2007, i can't access the site and it asks me to install sharepoint services or frontpage extensions. how can i modify the site using designer?

I know that in designer that the functionality exists to copy/paste a folder.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, see [this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492729/reducted-funtionality-using-fba-in-sharepoint). Essentially, it's by design and Microsoft don't give you that functionality. You could try turning on Client Integration but I don't know if it will work. If you need an alternative, searching around I found [UploadZen](http://roxority.com/uploadzen/) which seems to support multiple uploads with FBA.

Are you also using forms auth with SharePoint Designer? The bottom of [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/mhatch/archive/2007/03/10/sharepoint-2007-forms-authentication-and-aspnetsqlmembershipprovider.aspx) from Mike Hatch has information that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try out installing the SP2 for the SharePoint 2007 and the office Application. In the Office application they have solved may of the issue that were part of FBA enabled sites. Please refer to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/05/13/update-on-sharepoint-forms-based-authentication-fba-and-office-client.aspx) for more information.